# Erro Inaccessible logs: Security

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Boa Tarde, recentemente venho obtendo o seguinte erro

> The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be
>   searched. To create the source, you need permission to read all event
>   logs to make sure that the new source name is unique. Inaccessible
>   logs: Security.

Pelo que andei pesquisando na internet, encontrei soluções como executar o *Visual Studio* em modo Administrador, assim como criar uma nova *Key* no *path*:

> Key= 
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application\nomeDaAplicacao

Porém, o meu maior problema é que minha aplicação está hospedada no *Godaddy* e o mais estranho é que este erro vem ocorrendo apenas para alguns casos. Por exemplo: Tento gerar um relatório financeiro simples de alguma edição do meu projeto e obtenho esse erro acima, em algumas outras edições não tenho esse erro e gera o relatório como eu gostaria.

Alguém já enfrentou esse problema e sabe contornar?

Comment: Esse erro não acontece à toa. Você está usando alguma ferramenta de log que usa o Event Log do windows? Se não estiver, alguma biblioteca que usa em seu programa o está fazendo. Pode ser que você tenha ligado log para o eventlog no config da sua aplicação. Dá uma procurada por coisas desse tipo.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o meu problema. Acontece que alguém teve acesso ao banco de dados e alterou os valores de algumas linhas e quando tentava acessar para realizar cálculos, voltava esse erro.

Muito Obrigado a quem se prestou a me ajudar.